# Comparing and Sorting MongoDB ObjectIDs in Node - convert to string?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to compare, sort, filter, etc. arrays of MongoDB ObjectIDs as well as sort documents based on an arrays. My main question is: should I use `ObjectID.equals()` or is it okay to convert them all to strings, use native comparisons like `indexOf`, and convert them back? Does it matter?

My specific use case: a user can save posts to a list. I save this as an array of ObjectIDs `user.saves`. I want to retrieve the first 25 posts in order, so I query `{_id: {$in: user.saves.slice(0, 25)}}`. How would you sort retrieved documents?

Comment: If you are `$push`ing the objects onto a `saves()` array, aren't they already implicitly sorted?  Which documents are you trying to sort and retrieve .. are you doing another find() on objectIds `$in` the array?

Comment: yes. the only other way is to retrieve them in order is one by one, unless you have a better idea.

Comment: Don't really have many better ideas given I think you want a custom sort by the order in the `saves[]` array, rather than any property of the document you're retrieving.  Possibly it may be better to do the `$in` query and then a custom sort on the retrieved results (in your app code) rather than iterating by the `saves[]` order and doing 25 queries.

Comment: you basically restated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution:

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [{
    _id: _id1
  }, {
    _id: _id2
  }]
}, callback)
```

Answer (score -5):

The purpose of the ObjectId in Mongodb is to uniquely identify a document. 
You should never need use it for sorting operations, certainly by not converting to a string.

If all you want to do is get a list of documents sorted by the time they were created.
You should add created_at (timestamp) field, you can use this to sort the documents when you need to.

If you don't want to add the extra field. The ObjectId contains timestamp component, so you could extract this and use that for sorting. But the common way is to add the extra field.

Comment: 1) you don't need a created_at timestamp field because the ObjectID already has it. 2) never say never. 3) there's no "field" to add in this case. 4) this doesn't remotely solve my problem.

Comment: 1) it seems you can't read, I specifically mentioned that you can extract the timestamp from the objectId but that this not the common way to sort documents. 2) ObjectId's are not for sorting. 3) You are supposed to add the extra field so you can use it for sorting. 4) If you don't ask good questions and unable to read you will never solve your problem.

Comment: 1) http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sorting+and+Natural+Order 2) why would you even consider using a timestamp for subscriptions?

Comment: unless u want me to make a new document for every subscription like it's SQL, but that just complicates things for no reason

Comment: to be more specific, no i don't want documents by the time they were created. i want them in order of the list.